# Merge two time series

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to figure out how to merge two time series with different frequencies.The first time series are on 1 minute interval

```
 time1<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:02"),to=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01   13:10"),by="1 min")
 value<-round(matrix(runif(90,1,10),9,10),2)
 data<-data.frame(time1,value)
 data

                time1   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9  X10
1 2010-03-01 13:02:00 2.03 9.06 6.93 8.78 1.62 6.79 7.30 8.58 7.17 5.71
2 2010-03-01 13:03:00 6.68 6.36 1.32 1.32 7.40 6.46 5.86 9.22 7.48 2.56
3 2010-03-01 13:04:00 2.68 1.26 7.54 9.32 2.20 5.83 2.58 2.33 9.13 6.77
4 2010-03-01 13:05:00 9.82 9.78 2.73 6.68 8.59 8.18 4.59 3.84 6.65 9.28
5 2010-03-01 13:06:00 9.47 5.97 5.18 7.32 2.66 2.62 9.14 2.81 1.60 3.29
6 2010-03-01 13:07:00 9.11 4.92 2.03 3.10 3.77 9.96 7.30 8.19 6.06 6.32
7 2010-03-01 13:08:00 4.46 1.42 9.97 8.96 7.16 2.21 1.72 9.08 3.45 6.27 
8 2010-03-01 13:09:00 7.43 8.99 9.47 5.66 1.43 4.34 9.94 7.62 1.34 8.55
9 2010-03-01 13:10:00 6.10 2.09 6.47 3.83 7.05 9.65 4.84 1.34 6.14 6.63
```

The second time series are on 5 min interval

```
time2<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:10"),by="5 min")
value2<-round(matrix(runif(6,1,10),3,2),2)
data2<-data.frame(time2,value2)
data2
        time2   X1   X2
 1 2010-03-01 13:00:00 4.55 3.93
 2 2010-03-01 13:05:00 4.05 8.04
 3 2010-03-01 13:10:00 6.87 7.93
```

The preferred output would combine the two time series on the 5 minute interval so I would have a new data frame:

```
 1 2010-03-01 13:05:00 4.05 8.04 9.82 9.78 2.73 6.68 8.59 8.18 4.59 3.84 6.65 9.28
 2 2010-03-01 13:10:00 6.87 7.93 6.10 2.09 6.47 3.83 7.05 9.65 4.84 1.34 6.14 6.63
```

For sure there is simple function for this but I'm unable to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the columns used for merging have different names, you need to specify them using `by.x` (first table) and `by.y` (second table). Check `?merge` for more details.

```
merge(data2, data,  by.x = "time2", by.y = "time1")
```

**Output**

```
                time2 X1.x X2.x X1.y X2.y   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9  X10
1 2010-03-01 13:05:00 1.53 8.01 9.17 7.18 2.91 5.34 4.70 7.59 5.67 5.31 9.03 7.81
2 2010-03-01 13:10:00 6.78 8.18 6.66 9.93 1.12 7.02 5.77 3.20 5.13 8.55 4.91 2.29
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
time1<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:02"),to=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01   13:10"),by="1 min")
value<-round(matrix(runif(90,1,10),9,10),2)
data<-data.frame(time1,value)
data

                time1   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9  X10
1 2010-03-01 13:02:00 3.39 1.56 4.42 4.44 8.15 8.10 1.64 3.99 4.12 7.41
2 2010-03-01 13:03:00 4.35 2.85 8.00 8.83 1.97 1.21 1.90 6.86 4.00 4.60
3 2010-03-01 13:04:00 6.16 2.59 9.41 4.06 7.51 5.30 3.85 3.32 5.29 3.93
4 2010-03-01 13:05:00 9.17 7.18 2.91 5.34 4.70 7.59 5.67 5.31 9.03 7.81
5 2010-03-01 13:06:00 2.82 4.46 6.87 6.40 8.39 7.23 6.96 7.90 8.78 2.82
6 2010-03-01 13:07:00 9.09 7.93 2.13 5.44 6.82 5.30 4.66 1.76 4.51 7.40
7 2010-03-01 13:08:00 9.50 5.48 3.40 2.68 8.05 8.75 9.22 8.88 8.00 2.10
8 2010-03-01 13:09:00 6.95 7.46 4.48 8.45 5.98 4.94 3.64 4.05 9.65 3.21
9 2010-03-01 13:10:00 6.66 9.93 1.12 7.02 5.77 3.20 5.13 8.55 4.91 2.29

time2<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:10"),by="5 min")
value2<-round(matrix(runif(6,1,10),3,2),2)
data2<-data.frame(time2,value2)
data2

                time2   X1   X2
1 2010-03-01 13:00:00 3.16 8.89
2 2010-03-01 13:05:00 1.53 8.01
3 2010-03-01 13:10:00 6.78 8.18
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# MERGE DATA SETS IF ELEMENTS ARE THE SAME IN COLUMN A
require(reshape2)

# Set WD
setwd("C:\\your_path_here\\")

# Load data from all CSV files 
NumOne <- c("Book1.csv")
NumOneData <- as.matrix((read.csv(NumOne,header=T,sep=",",check.names = F)))


NumTwo = c("Book2.csv")
NumTwoData <- as.matrix((read.csv(NumTwo,header=T,sep=",",check.names = F)))



myfulldata1 = merge(NumOneData, NumTwoData)
write.table(myfulldata1, file = "C:\\your_path_here\\foo1.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA, qmethod = "double")


NumOneData$CONTRIBUTING_GROUP <- match(NumOneData$CONTRIBUTING_GROUP, NumTwoData$CONTRIBUTING_GROUP, nomatch=0)
write.table(nomatch, file = "C:\\your_path_here\\foo2.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA, qmethod = "double")

merged.data.all3 <- merge(NumOneData, NumTwoData, by="CONTRIBUTING_GROUP", all=TRUE)
write.table(merged.data.all3, file = "C:\\your_path_here\\foo3.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA, qmethod = "double")


# mydata <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("country","year"))

# When common ids have different names use by.x and by.y to match them. R will keep the name of the first dataset (by.x) 
# When different variables from two different dataset have the same name, R will assign a suffix .x or .y to make them unique and to identify which dataset they are coming from.
# mydata <- merge(mydata1, mydata2, by.x=c("country","year"), by.y=c("nations","time"))

# Note: The default setting of the merge() function drops all unmatched cases. If you want to keep all cases in the new data set, include the option all=TRUE in the merge() function:
# merged.data.all <- merge(dataset1, dataset2, by="countryID", all=TRUE)
```

You should probably keep these in a safe place as well.

```
Inner join: merge(df1, df2) will work for these examples because R automatically joins the frames by common variable names, but you would most likely want to specify merge(df1, df2, by = "CustomerId") to make sure that you were matching on only the fields you desired. You can also use the by.x and by.y parameters if the matching variables have different names in the different data frames.

Outer join: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all = TRUE)

Left outer: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all.x = TRUE)

Right outer: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all.y = TRUE)

Cross join: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = NULL)
```

All those concepts come from here.

[How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0):

a simple merge will do

```
time1<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:02"),to=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01   13:10"),by="1 min")
value<-round(matrix(runif(90,1,10),9,10),2)
data<-data.frame(time=time1,value)
time2<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2010-03-01 13:10"),by="5 min")
value2<-round(matrix(runif(6,1,10),3,2),2)
data2<-data.frame(time=time2,value2)
merge(data2,data,by="time")
```